# Testing an exports function in a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Dialogflow in google in Javascript. I need to test the function identify_customer_by_name and using the following construct, how do I invoke the function?

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // Get the city and date from the request
  const agent = new WebhookClient({
    request,
    response
  });


  function identify_customer_by_name(agent) {
  }
```

)

Comment: Can you please share the actual code, or if simplified, at least a working snippet? Due to the unmatched parenthesis, it's hard to say whether `identify_customer_by_name` is declared inside the `onRequest` callback or not.

Comment: Unless the function you need can somehow be referenced via `exports`, it means it is not exported, so you cannot access it outside. Here it is not exported, its scope is the _inside_ of an exported function.